# Uploading a file from a user directory to the server, using XMLHttpRequest and FormData

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon

I have a Firefox extension which writes some data into a text file and stores it somewhere in the user directory.
I want to send this file to a remote server. I initiate a file object and append to the `FormData`. But I get error 400 (bad request) as a response from the server side.
I read couple of articles but all of them assume that there is a HTML form to choose file from it.
**EDITED**: I removed the setRequestHeader line. I don't get that error any more but $_Files is empty and $_Post is [file] => [xpconnect wrapped nsILocalFile].

This is my upload method:

```
var remote_server = "http://foo.com/test/?";
function uploadFile(data)
{
var xmlHttp = null;
fileName = "C:/Users/pro/firefox/test.txt";
    var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].
              createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
    file.initWithPath(fileName);
var form_data = new FormData();                  
    form_data.append("file", file); 

xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "POST", remote_server, false );
//xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data");   
    xmlHttp.send(form_data);
response = xmlHttp.responseText
return response;
}
```

And here is the simple PHP code on my server side:

```
<?php
echo "hi test";
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
?>
```

**EDITED**: I removed the setRequestHeader line. I don't get that error any more but $_Files is empty and $_Post is [file] => [xpconnect wrapped nsILocalFile]. Below image shows the HTTP packet that is sent from client to the server.

[image: here is the print screen of wireshark]

Comment: (my) stupid question.. where are you defining `remote_server`?

Comment: @CrayonViolent in the beginning of my js file like remote_server="http://foo.com/test"

Comment: can you post a network trace of the client sending the bad request and response, so that we can see the actual request and raw headers sent, etc..? Basically the core issue is that the request is somehow formatted wrong so server is rejecting it.  Also, do you have access to the server receiving the request? Can you look at the logs to get the error logged from it?

Comment: @CrayonViolent Please have a look to the edited part